# Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ini_set()

Tags: php, laravel

I deployed my Laravel project on server. I am facing this issue. Ran `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update --no-scripts` commands but the problem remain same. This laravel v-8.83 and php v-8.1 project .

[image: Here is the screenshot of error message what I get]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with PHP.

You have to enable mbstring extension in php.ini.

You must have a line like this in it : `;extension = php_mbstring.dll`

Just uncomment by removing the `;`