# How can i deploy a laravel website to CPanel using github actions

Tags: laravel, deployment, cpanel

**I am trying to deploy a laravel project to cpanel but constantly getting wierd errors.**
**I have been following the following steps and followed differnt youtube tutorilas, and ask ChatGPT and even Bing, but still the same issues**

1. created a brand new laravel project
2. setup github and connected with ftp
   **here's how my gitignore file looks like/ i have seperately uploaded the vendor and public folder using the zipping uploading and then unzipping technique.**

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

/nbproject/private/
```

** setup github workflow. here's the workflow yaml file configuration. which i also copied **

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
name:  Deploy file on FTP
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Use Node.js 14
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: '14'

    - name:  Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.2.0
      with:
        server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
        username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
        exclude: |
          **/.git*
          **/.git*/**
          **/node_modules/**
          **/public/**
          **/vendor/**
```

** now everythin on my local setup is on the cloud but still getting the error shown below, what am i doing wrong and any suggestions for stream lining the process, and pro tips **

```
Symfony Exception
Symfony Docs
Error
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ini_set()
```

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nQuW.png) 
[page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k57cf.png)

thanks in advance, ✌

tried almost everthing local zip uploads github actions everything,still getting the same errors

Comment: Laravel on shared hosting is pain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ini\_set()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73385507/call-to-undefined-function-illuminate-foundation-bootstrap-ini-set)